# Bash history search, partial + up-arrow

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, history

I have searched, but not found anything on this. I am looking for a functionality in bash, using a terminal.

Way back when, I had a user on a debian system, and a friend set me up with a convenient history search feature (I believe I used tcsh then), where I would type the beginning of a previous command, hit up-arrow, and it would do a search, based on the partial string.

E.g. if my history is:

```
./script.pl
./script.pl arg1
cat output
cat output | grep yada
```

And I type `.`, and press up-arrow, it would show me: `./script.pl arg1`. Press it again and it would show `./script.pl`, etc.

Very much like it would perform a `grep` on .bash_history. Is there a way to get this functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPython Like Command History For Shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12368/ipython-like-command-history-for-shell)

Comment: @Marcel Looks like it might be the same answer, I saw that in the search, but didn't connect it to my question, with the iPython and Shell keywords.

Comment: Sounds like this - https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Create `~/.inputrc` and add these lines:

```
# Respect default shortcuts.
$include /etc/inputrc

## arrow up
"\e[A":history-search-backward
## arrow down
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

> **TIP:** Read at the bottom for an explanation of `$include /etc/inputrc` or what to do if you already have the file `~/.inputrc`.

Lines starting with `#` are comments.

I can't remember what is backward and what forward. Experiment with it. Maybe you have to switch backward and forward.

Close and re-open all terminals for the new behaviour to become effective.

---

A bit background information:

Bash is using [readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) to handle the prompt. `~/.inputrc` is the configuration file for readline. Note that this will also take effect in other software using the readline library, for example [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython).

Read the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing) for more information about readline. There you can also find more [history related readline commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History).

To get the escape codes for the arrow keys you can do the following:

1. Start `cat` in a terminal (just `cat`, no further arguments).
2. Type keys on keyboard, you will get things like `^[[A` for up arrow and `^[[B` for down arrow.
3. Replace `^[` with `\e`.

For more information about `^[` and `\e` see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89817/380515

---

About the line `$include /etc/inputrc`:

Readline tries to read `~/.inputrc` for configuration. If that file does not exists it will try to read `/etc/inputrc`. That means if `~/.inputrc` exists it will not read `/etc/inputrc`.

Some distros have prepared some config in `/etc/inputrc`. If you then create `~/.inputrc` you will lose the prepared config. This may or may not be what you want. To still keep the prepared config in `/etc/inputrc` you can use the line `$include /etc/inputrc` in your `~/.inputrc`.

If you already have the file `~/.inputrc` that means you either already know what you are doing. Or you inherited if from the person who set up your system. Or you previously followed a different guide which told you to create the file and forgot about it. Either way you might want to check `/etc/inputrc` and decide if you want to keep it with the line `$include /etc/inputrc`.

Comment: Great, but this solution disables the ctrl-left/ctrl-right shortcuts.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I achieve the same for make

Comment: @lesmana, i would give extra points for the cat part alone

Comment: Seconding @Eyal, anyone have advice on how I can have this but preserve ctrl-left/ctrl-right shortcuts?

Comment: Figured it out, somehow readline must have been inferring some default if .inputrc did not exist, but got rid of those defaults when the file was detected. In addition to the shortcuts from the answer, add lines to preserve the ctrl-left/ctrl-right shortcuts: e.g. `"\e[1;5C":forward-word` and `"\e[1;5D":backward-word`

Comment: To preserve all defaults add `$include /etc/inputrc`, preferably on the first line.

Comment: @Eyal, [to fix that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59846/bash-history-search-partial-up-arrow#comment1080454_59855) checkout [Why does ctrl + left arrow not skip words?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162247/283843)

Comment: Is there any reason why after certain commands in bash, this behavior is broken? I will need another bash for it to work again.

Comment: This is just writing ~ symbols in my shell.

Comment: In addition to the above answer, you can find all key codes here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: I removed the comments for the lines "\e[5~": history-search-backward
 "\e[6~": history-search-forward in my existing /etc/inputrc file

Answer (score 53):

Create a file named setup_readline.sh with mode 644 in /etc/profile.d/ with following content, login and check you preferred keys:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

I think is the best way to do this. Mostly if you using configuration management systems  such as chef, puppet, etc

And system config still untouched!

Comment: Oddly the ~/inputrc didn't work for me - but putting these commands into .bash_profile did.

Comment: .inputrc doesn't exist in my home folder and I prefer to have these kind of settings in .bashrc anyway so I can just carry around one file for my settings. So this is probably a better answer then accepted one.

Comment: .inputrc works fabulously for me, but not after I load `screen`.  The odd thing is, other .inputrc shortcuts work, but not these.   So I use both solutions now.

Comment: This is super-helpful when, for example, you log into a server to do things and are missing the heck out of these and don't want to edit and reload the ~/.inputrc on the server.

Comment: You should be able to put these in `~/.inputrc` if you remove the `bind` keyword and the `'` single-quotes.

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> will give you this sort of functionality. Start typing a partial command and it will come up with old ones which you can navigate with the up and down arrows.

More info [here](http://www.nuxified.org/blog/ctrl_r_in_the_bash_shell).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have tried that, but I find it a bit... finicky. It will not allow me to scroll through commands beginning with the partial, it only shows the first. It also searches the entire command for the character, which is sort of useless.

Comment: @TLP, repeat hitting `Ctrl+r`

Comment: `ctrl+R` doesn't do the up/down arrow by default. You can only repeat `ctrl+R` to "search up". There is no "search down".

Comment: @wisbucky there's "search down"; unfortunately, by default, it's not available. `stty -ixon` "enables" it.

Answer (score 7):

The following solution combines & extends some of the above mentioned approaches:
add the following lines to your `~/.bash_aliases` file (no need for `~/.inputrc`) in order to achieve the following behavior:

1. move up/down in history (only entries with same prefix) by pressing CTRL+UP and CTRL+DOWN. This can co-exist to the standard functionality of moving up/down in the full history via UP and DOWN alone
2. jump to next/previous word in a commandline by pressing CTRL+RIGHT and CTRL+LEFT

```
bind '"\e[1;5A":history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[1;5B":history-search-forward'
bind '"\e[1;5C":forward-word'
bind '"\e[1;5D":backward-word'
```

Re-login to the shell (or run `source ./bash_aliases`) in order to apply the changes.

Comment: Hi, do you know where I can find out about how to create more complicated keyboard shortcuts? Perhaps what this notation is called etc?

Comment: Related terms are "keycode" or "scancode" (I am no expert). However, pragmatic solution: Running `showkey -a` gives you helpful output, e.g., "^[[1;5A" which means "\e[1;5A", that is, the leading "^[" seems to refer to "\e".

Comment: the second point seems to be the default anyways, and this does not work for me - had to remove the `1;5`

Answer (score 6):

To complete lesmana's answer regarding `~/.inputrc` that I should create under my Trusty 14.04, verify/add in `~/.bashrc` (the first line already exists in my `~/.bashrc`):

```
shopt -s histappend  
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

It's already explained in French [here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/terminal?&#pour_completer_les_commandes_a_partir_de_l_historique).

Comment: This command basically instructs bash to immediately append command to history file instead of waiting for session to end. Its useful if you have lot of terminals open and don't want to loose history in one but otherwise not necessary. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you may want to try https://github.com/dvorka/hstr which provides simple and multi-line simple filtering of Bash history which as based on a metrics (when, how often and length of commands matters) - you can use arrow keys to easily navigate the history:

[image]

It can be easily [bound](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) to <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative similar to what @lesmana mentioned above, but you do not have to create a new .inputrc file.

Instead, if you have sudo permissions, you can enable this in the /etc/inputrc file. In this file are various keyboard settings including the history search feature (for 18.04 at least). The excerpt from /etc/inputrc is:

```
# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Uncomment the bottom two lines using a sudo file editor (e.g., $ sudo vim), and a new terminal session will have the history search feature (for all users). This way, you do not have to worry about creating a ~/.inputrc file, nor will you have to add an `$include` statement as @Tulio Casagrande mentioned in the comments to preserve your ctrl-arrow inputs.

Comment: Good idea but you also have to change "\e[5~" to "\e[A"  and "\e[6~" to "\e[B" or it won't work.