# How to see command history?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I recently saw an article on the internet. Using that  by typing the first letter and pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> would show me the command starting with that letter.
For example let this be my command history:

```
sudo -s
ls
nautilus
```

Now if I type <kbd>s</kbd> and press <kbd>↑</kbd> would show me

```
sudo -s
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Type `history` in Terminal. All command history are stored in `~/.bash_history` file

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash history search, partial + up-arrow](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59846/bash-history-search-partial-up-arrow)

Comment: Your question is _How to see command history?_ and my answer is current for your question. change your question title first.

Comment: I able not able to figure out an appropriate one. Will you help me in figuring out a title for this quesion?

Comment: The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title is clear [_like yours_], they won't read the rest

Answer (score 2):

Two more useful things to know about this...

To execute a specific command from your history, you can just type an exclamation point followed by the number of the command as listed by history. So, to re-execute command number 510.

```
!510
```

To rerun your previous command just type two exclamation points. So when you run a command that needs super-user privileges and you forgot to do that - just give it the old “sudo bang bang” treatment:

```
sudo !!
```

Comment: Did you see the example in my question?