# Ubuntu shortcut for getting last matching history command

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

When I was using Linux before I remember that I had a pretty useful shortcut. It was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> (There was also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> which did the opposite way) and it worked as follows: For example I typed `/he` in the terminal (without pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>). If I press `CTRL+UP` it shows the last command that was ran with prefix `/he`. If I press again, it will go up and up in the history commands. Example:

```
> history
cat text1.txt
cat text2.txt
cat text3.txt
```

If I write `cat` in the terminal and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> it will switch to `cat text3.txt` and if I press again it will switch to `cat text2.txt`. Is there some similar shortcut in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

```
## arrow up
"\e[A":history-search-backward
## arrow down
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

From [Bash history search, partial + up-arrow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59846/bash-history-search-partial-up-arrow)

Is this what you were looking for?